# My JSON, PHP do not work

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is my php code saved as db2.php

```
<?php

      mysql_connect("mysql15.000webhost.com","a3189966_root","");

      mysql_select_db("a3189966_pd");
      $firstName = $_GET[firstName];
      echo $firstName;
      $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people where first='$firstName'");

      while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
              $output[]=$e;

            $json = json_encode($output);
            echo($json);

    mysql_close();

?>
```

This is my html code with jquery and json saved as index2.html

```
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){
                    var postData = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
                        url: "db2.php",
                        success: function(data){
                            alert("processing now" + data);
                                  $.each(data,function(i,item){
                                                          alert("processing each data now");
                                      $('<li></li>').html(item.first + " " + item.last).appendTo('#data');
                                  });
                        },
                        error: function(data){alert("failed"+data);}
                    });
                return false;
                });

    <form id="myForm" method="GET" action="">
    <input type="textbox" name="firstName" id="firstName">
    <input type="submit" name="myButton" value="submit">
</form>
<ul id="data">
</ul>
```

After I have executed the html code below, it only prompt out the error.
I have checked for few hours, and I can't see any error for this code to be executed correctly.
This is the json object return from the php

```
[{"id":"1","first":"wen","last":"hao","age":"123"}]
```

Comment: I think it's because you don't declare `$output = array();` outside of the while loop. Also, why jsonp if you don't need a callback function to be passed to execute the json?

Comment: Please change this line before you put this code on a web server: $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people where first='$firstName'");  Read up on SQL injection and how to prevent it

Comment: [Why is $foo\[bar\] wrong?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Comment: Cool, will check on the sql injection..~

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error callback for the ajax call can take three arguments. The second and third arguments should give you a better idea of what's going wrong.

From the [jQuery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are
>   "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error
>   occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status,
>   such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."

So try something like this for your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
    url: "db2.php",
    success: function(data){
        alert("processing now" + data);
        $.each(data,function(i,item){
            alert("processing each data now");
             $('<li></li>').html(item.first + " " + item.last).appendTo('#data');
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        if(errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: After I have submitted the form, the url is http://programmerpig.vacau.com/index2.php?firstName=wen&myButton=submit
and 2 alerts prompted
The first alert is parseerror
The second alert is syntaxerror: unexpected token w

Comment: After I have removed the echo $firstName in the php file, everything work fine ..~ I think the error is on the syntaxerror for the unexpected token w

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Is there a reason you are printing $firstName in db2.php? Everything you want to send back should be in $output, since that is the data being encoded into JSON

Comment: I print the $firstName in db2.php is because of I wan to ensure that the data is passed to db2.php ..~

Answer (score 1):

Change your `dataType` from `jsonp` to `json`.

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: The error was the message in the error section if the ajax failed.

Comment: @user970307 Look at the response, what response did you get?

Comment: @user970307 I mean the http response, anyway, what did you get if you access directly by `db2.php?firstName=foo`

Comment: I will get foo[] if firstName=foo

Comment: if i put in the firstName=wen then i get [{"id":"1","first":"wen","last":"hao","age":"123"}]

Comment: @user970307 If it is 200, means success, why will the error callback execute? You must miss something.

Comment: I'm also not sure, everything is ok if I don't include the data:$(this).serialize() (if i select * from people)
Once I pass something to the php, everything goes down ..

Comment: @user970307 Of course, if you echo something else except the json, it break the json. The response could not be parsed.